Analyze the variance of one adaptive process?
I'm currently interested in analyzing the variance of one adaptive process. To be more specific, suppose I have done some, let's say $n$ times, experiments where the results depend on some unknown parameter $\theta$. I now use maximum likelihood estimator $\hat\theta_{\mathrm{MLE}}$ to estimate $\theta$. Based on this estimate, I then adjust my experiment based on $\hat\theta_{\mathrm{MLE}}$ and do $n$ times experiments again. Then I estimate $\theta$ based on the newly observed data. I repeat the above process sufficiently many times.
My problem is, how can I analyze the variance about the estimate of $\theta$ for the whole process? Are there some references about the variance of one adaptive process I can refer to?
